# Getting width of an element defined in CSS in em

Tags: javascript, css, styles, width

I am having trouble getting the width of an element defined in CSS. I figured out how to get the CSS rules using Javascript, but I can't access the width. **Menu** is fixed width that I defined in CSS using **em**.

I am trying to change the width of the **div1** based on the browser window minus the fixed **menu width**.

Note: I already tried using `style.width`, but it returns a blank line in the console.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kj6pQ/

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div'), 
css = getMatchedCSSRules(document.getElementById('menu'));

console.log(css); //works but dont' konw how to access width

div1.style.width = window.innerWidth - <!-- menu width -->;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use '`offsetWidth`' to access the menu's width

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div'), 
css = document.getElementById('menu').offsetWidth;

console.log(css);
div1.style.width = css + "px";
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
var css = document.getElementById('menu');

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(css).width);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kj6pQ/6/

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var width = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("menu"), null).getPropertyValue("width");
```